# Why can't I instantiate a child class on its parent Generic Interface?

Tags: c#

I have the following arrangement:

```
public interface Inter<T>{}


public class Child : Inter<int> {}
```

When I try to instantiate Child like this:

```
Inter<object> a = new Child();
```

The compiler complains that it can't convert Child into Inter< object>.

However, if I try the following:

```
IEnumerable<object> list = new List<string>();
```

It works just fine.

The question is, why the first instantiation throws a Conversion Error and the second doesn't?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) `IEnumerable`'s type parameter is explicitly declared with `out`, so it's covariant. Your `Inter<T>` type parameter is invariant. 2) Generic variance doesn't work with value type arguments like `int` - so `IEnumerable<object> list = new List<int>();` won't work either

Comment: More on that: [Generics/Convariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)